# Отслеживание ошибок в React-приложении

Tags: javascript, reactjs, обработка-ошибок

Есть react-приложение (расширение для браузера). Хотелось бы отслеживать ошибки, которые происходят при его использовании пользователем. Как это сделать? Какие сервисы/технологии для этого можно использовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bugsnag](https://www.bugsnag.com/) - очень популярный сервис для отслеживания ошибок на продакшене. Необходимо подключить скрипт Bugsnag в ваше расширение и когда в нем произойдет ошибка, Bugsnag перехватит ее и отправлять на свой сервер. После чего можно будет удобно просматривать ошибки и статистику по ним.